# Dapper > I cannot retrieve object with child object

Tags: dapper

I have the following Quote and Share classes:

```
public class Quote
{
    public Quote(string ticker, string name, decimal lastPrice)
    {
        this.Ticker = ticker;
        this.Name = name;
        this.LastPrice = lastPrice;
    }

    public string Ticker { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public decimal LastPrice { get; private set; }
}

public class Share
{
    public Share(Quote quote, int quantity)
    {
        this.Quote = quote;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Quote Quote { get; private set; }
    public int Quantity { get; private set; }
}
```

And these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[quotes](
[ticker] [char](5) NOT NULL,
[name] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
[last_price] [money] NOT NULL,
[bid_price] [money] NULL,
[bid_quantity] [int] NULL,
[ask_price] [money] NULL,
[ask_quantity] [int] NULL,
[high] [money] NULL,
[low] [money] NULL,
[previous_close] [money] NULL,
[created_by] [varchar](12) NULL,
[created_date] [datetime] NULL,
[modified_by] [varchar](12) NULL,
[modified_date] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_quotes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ticker] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  =     ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[shares](
[ticker] [char](5) NOT NULL,
[broker_id] [char](12) NOT NULL,
[quantity] [int] NOT NULL,
[created_by] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
[created_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[modified_by] [varchar](12) NULL,
[modified_date] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_shares] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ticker] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,            IGNORE_DUP_KEY        =     OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)     ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[shares]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_shares_quotes]     FOREIGN KEY([ticker])
REFERENCES [dbo].[quotes] ([ticker])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[shares] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_shares_quotes]
GO
```

And finally this code:

```
        string sql = "SELECT quantity, s.ticker, name, last_price FROM shares s " +
                     "INNER JOIN quotes q ON q.ticker = s.ticker " +
                     "WHERE s.ticker=@ticker AND broker_id = @broker_Id";

        IEnumerable<Share> shares = connection.Query<Share, Quote, Share>(sql,
                                        (s, q) =>
                                        {
                                            Share share = new Share(q, s.Quantity);
                                            return share;
                                        },
                                        new { ticker = ticker, broker_Id = brokerId }
                                        , splitOn: "ticker");

        return shares.FirstOrDefault();
```

When I execute that query, I get the following error:

**"Specified method is not supported" (???)**

If I modify the sql statement by the following (with "last_price as lastPrice"):

```
string sql = "SELECT quantity, s.ticker, name, last_price as lastPrice FROM shares s " +
                     "INNER JOIN quotes q ON q.ticker = s.ticker " +
                     "WHERE s.ticker=@ticker AND broker_id = @broker_Id";
```

I get the following error:

**"A parameterless default constructor or one matching signature (System.String ticker, System.String name, System.Decimal lastPrice) is required for Footstock.Domain.Model.Quote materialization"**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding a parameterless `Share` constructor. My guess is that Dapper is trying to build the `Share` object to pass into the `(s, q) => ...` method and all it has is the `quantity`.

Comment: Since that worked for you and I had enough time to write an actual answer, I posted it. Please accept it (via the green checkmark) if you found it useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `Share` class, you need to either add a parameterless constructor or one that takes only a `quantity` parameter.

Before Dapper calls the method that composes the result to be returned, it needs to build the parameters to pass in to `(s, q) => ...` In your case you need a `Share` and a `Quote` class, both of which must have a constructor that can be called using the data Dapper has. For `Quote`, the constructor matches the properties in the query. For `Share`, Dapper only has the `quantity` and does not have a `Quote` object yet.